# How to implement a messaging feature in android application to other android devices and to computers

Tags: java, android, cloud

I've been working on an android application and I am trying to figure out how to implement a messaging feature for the application to send messages to other phones and to my web app. I have been doing a fair amount of research and I haven't yet found any ways of going about this, or at least not any straightforward ones. Could someone point me in the right direction with this? Is there a relatively simple way to get this functionality? I have found links that show how to use google's cloud service but I am extremely unfamiliar with this so I was wondering if there were other better/simpler implementations or instructions out there. Thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 0):

For security and privacy reasons, your phone/tablet app cannot (should not) communicate directly with other devices (unless they're on the same WiFi or similar and explicitly bound via bluetooth .etc)

So the way to do this on Android is use Cloud to Device Messaging (C2DM).

1. Your app will send a web request to your server, with the message and intended recipients.
2. Your server will look at this, find the C2DM IDs of the recipients, and send the message to Google's C2DM service, which will then be pushed down to each device.

Your app should have a C2DM receiver to receive these messages and process them.

Check here for more information on implementing C2DM
http://code.google.com/android/c2dm/

Comment: So can this service be used for android to android communication, android to computer communication, and vice-versa?

Comment: In theory... yes... but it is meant to be used as the way to push messages from your back-end server to your android client.

You can potentially host a server in android app, and push messages to other phones, although I don't recommend it. If you are looking for something like a chat app without a server, look for XMPP/Jabber.